# Position relative child of an absolute positioned element

Tags: css, css-position

How should children with `position: relative` behave inside of a parent that has `position: absolute`?

For example ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7nfrq868/)):

```
<div style="position:relative; float:left; min-width:900px; max-width: 1400px; height:100%;">
  <div style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0; width:200px; height:300px;">
    <div style="position:relative; top:0; left:0; width:500px; height:100%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I shrink the browser window below the max-width the inner div moves outside of its parent element. Is that normal behavior?

Comment: Please make your question more clear... what do you mean exactly with "moves outside of its parent element"? Can you give more context?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from : http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

> **Relative** *[...]* What it really means is "relative to itself". If you set `position: relative;` on an element but **no other positioning attributes** (top, left, bottom or right), it will **no effect** on it's positioning at all, it will be exactly as it would be if you left it as position: static; But if you DO give it some other positioning attribute, say, `top: 10px;`, it will shift it's position 10 pixels DOWN from where it would *NORMALLY* be. *[...]*

Answer (score 0):

Try changing a few things. First, give your first div an actual height rather than just 100%. Second, try making the child element fit within its parent. Right now it's a 500px div inside a 200px div. It might be better positioned outside the parent for this specific task.